# Port Forwarding to my LT2P Client - MikroTik RouterOS

Tags: networking, router, vpn, port-forwarding, mikrotik-routeros

I have a VPS Hosting a L2TP/IPsec VPN. My MikroTik Router is has the VPN configured and has a connection successfully established to it.

```
VLAN 3127 (172.31.1.0/27)
LT2P VPN  (192.168.42.0/24)
```

I am trying to port-forward 172.31.1.5 to 192.168.42.10.

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-address=192.168.42.10 protocol=tcp dst-port=22 action=dst-nat to-addresses=172.31.1.5 to-ports=22

/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat dst-address=192.168.42.10 protocol=udp dst-port=33001 action=dst-nat to-addresses=172.31.1.5 to-ports=33001
```

SSH onto TCP 192.168.42.10:22 - Timeout

Connect to Game Server UDP 192.168.42.10:33001 - Timeout